# Flipping line endings in C++ (or R)

Tags: c++, r

I have a C++ that I'm running though R (via Rcpp).  Recently, I found that the C++ program I'm wrapping with Rcpp fails when using Windows-style line endings.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a cross-platform way for me to change Windows-style line endings to Unix-style line endings in either C++ or R or ash shell (which comes installed with R).

Thanks!

Comment: It rather try to fix the C++ program. Seems cleaner. Otherwise use `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 1):

Use R function `readLines`, which is immune to various LEs, and then pass string vector to C++. Or, if you don't like to change the C++ part, use `paste` to change the LEs to whatever you want.